# Erlang : variable 'Result' unsafe in 'try'

Tags: syntax, compiler-construction, scope, erlang, try-catch

I'm using Erlang R16B03.

This code:

```
list_dir(Directory, Retries) when is_integer(Retries), Retries > 0 ->
    Port = get_efile_port(),
    try erlang:port_info(Port) of
        Result ->
            error_logger:info_msg("list_dir - erlang:port_info(~p) ->  ~p ", [Port,Result])
    catch
        _:Reason ->
             error_logger:info_msg("list_dir - erlang:port_info(~p) -> {error, ~p }",[Port,Reason])
    end,
    case prim_file:list_dir(Port, Directory) of
        {error, einval} ->
            error_logger:info_msg(" list_dir -  port : ~p , directory : ~p", [Port, Directory]),
            clear_efile_port(),
            list_dir(Directory, Retries-1);
        Result ->
            Result
    end.
```

Generates the following compiler exception:

```
/basho/riak/deps/bitcask/src/bitcask_fileops.erl:855: variable 'Result' unsafe in 'try' (line 843)
ERROR: compile failed while processing /basho/riak/deps/bitcask: rebar_abort
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

But if I rename the first use of the variable name `Result` to `Res`, it compiles fine, e.g:

```
list_dir(Directory, Retries) when is_integer(Retries), Retries > 0 ->
    Port = get_efile_port(),
    try erlang:port_info(Port) of
        Res ->
            error_logger:info_msg("list_dir - erlang:port_info(~p) ->  ~p ", [Port,Res])
    catch
        _:Reason ->
             error_logger:info_msg("list_dir - erlang:port_info(~p) -> {error, ~p }",[Port,Reason])
    end,
    case prim_file:list_dir(Port, Directory) of
        {error, einval} ->
            error_logger:info_msg(" list_dir -  port : ~p , directory : ~p", [Port, Directory]),
            clear_efile_port(),
            list_dir(Directory, Retries-1);
        Result ->
            Result
    end.
```

As far as I can see the variables are within two different scopes (try/catch and case).

Is this a compiler bug or have I failed to understand the Erlang syntax correctly?

Answer (score 9):

This is not a compiler bug. The problem is that in the first example, you use `Result` in two places: first in the `try`, and then again in the `case`. These are not two different scopes, but the same scope. The compiler is complaining because if there's no exception raised in the `try`, `Result` will be bound to the result of the `erlang:port_info(Port)` call, but if that call raises an exception, `Result` will not be bound. This means its use within the `case` will be ambiguous, since in the second `case` clause it would be matched if it's already bound, or bound to the result of `prim_file:list_dir(Port, Directory)` if it's not already bound.

Answer (score 4):

The try block itself returns a value. So you can avoid these situations like this

```
list_dir(Directory, Retries) when is_integer(Retries), Retries > 0 ->
    Port = get_efile_port(),
    Result = try erlang:port_info(Port) of
          ...
```

etc.

For example, here's a couple of lines from a project I'm working on right now:

```
F = try
      python:call(P, 'python.repo_admin_cmd', 'repo_admin_cmd', [erlang:list_to_binary(Command) || Command <- Commands])
catch error:{python, _Class, _Argument, _StackTrace} ->
     error
end
```

If I were to try to assign "F" inside the "try" I'd get the same error you did!

Answer (score 2):

Since you've matched to your `Result` clause, result is bound to value. And its scope is not restricted by block. Consider following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env escript

main([What]) ->
    case What of
        Value when Value == "hello" ->
            Result = foo(Value),
            ok; 
        Value when Value == "goodbye" ->
            Result = foo(Value),
            ok  
    end,
    io:format("~p ~p",[Result, Value]).

foo("hello") ->
    "ohai";

foo("goodbye") ->
    "cya".
```

Even `Value` was bound only in `case` clause, it's still accessible in outer scope. Notice that same thing with `Result` variable which bounded in case clause too.